# error Iterating through OrderedDict in Python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.4

I am trying to iterate through an OrderedDict using {Key, Value} but i am running into Key Error. The iteritems() was deprecated in python 3.4 that i am using and now i have to use items() to do the same thing

```
 File "/home/hotdogs/mydictset.py", line 88, in __init__
 self.mainParams[k]['start'], self.mainParams[k]['step'], self.mainParams[k] ['stop'])
 KeyError: 'timed_exit_bars'


class MySet()
  def __init__(self, filePath):
    # Read diagnostics set file
    self.content = readSetFile(filePath)
    if not self.content: return
    self.sections = self.content._sections
    self.mainParams = {}
    self.optimizationArray = {}
    global paramIndexes

    #for k, v in OrderedDict(self.content.items('main')).iteritems(): --was from python 2.7 and i have removed it.

    for k, v in OrderedDict(self.content.items('main')).items():
        # Add the params names avoiding the optimization line
        if k.find(",") == -1:
            # Adding name of the param and the value
            if k not in self.mainParams:
                self.mainParams[k] = {}
            self.mainParams[k]['value'] = v
            # optimization flags
            if self.content.has_option('main', k + ',F'):
                if self.content.getboolean('main', k + ',F') == 1:
                    self.mainParams[k]['optimize'] = True
                    self.mainParams[k]['start'] = self.content.getfloat('main', k + ',1')
                    self.mainParams[k]['step'] = self.content.getfloat('main', k + ',2')
                    self.mainParams[k]['stop'] = self.content.getfloat('main', k + ',3')
                    self.optimizationArray[paramIndexes[k]] = (
                    self.mainParams[k]['start'], self.mainParams[k]['step'], self.mainParams[k]['stop'])
                else:
                    self.mainParams[k]['optimize'] = False
            else:
                self.mainParams[k]['optimize'] = False

    i = 0
```

When i try to debug the Key error . i see that the mainParams contains just an ordinary unsorted dict and the parameters themselves are also ordinary dict themselves from the debug below . Sample is below

```
  {'section_1': {'value': '################# General Settings #################', 'optimize': False}, 
  'run_every_tick': {'value': '0', 'optimize': False}, 
  'historic_data_id': {'value': '1', 'optimize': False}, 
  'section_2': {'value': '############## Common Strategy Settings ##############','optimize': False}, 
  'use_instance_balance': {'value': '0', 'optimize': False}, 
  'comments': {'value': 'Click Modify expert to view comments inside the source code.', 'optimize': False}, 
  'operational_mode': {'value': '1', 'optimize': False}, 
  'instance_management': {'value': '0', 'optimize': False}, 
  'analysis_window_size': {'value': '0', 'optimize': False}, 
  'enable_screenshots': {'value': '0', 'optimize': False}, 
  'timed_exit_bars': {'step': 5.0, 'start': 5.0, 'value': '60', 'stop': 100.0, 'optimize': True}, 
  'max_open_orders': {'value': '1', 'optimize': False}, 
  'strategy_timeframe': {'value': '60', 'optimize': False}, 
  'ui_font_size': {'value': '12', 'optimize': False},  
  'disable_compounding': {'value': '1', 'optimize': False}}
```

Below is a sample of what i get through Debug for ParamIndexes

```
{
'INTERNAL_STRATEGY_ID': 52, 
'RUN_EVERY_TICK': 43, 
'MAX_OPEN_ORDERS': 45, 
'OPERATIONAL_MODE': 50, 
'ANALYSIS_WINDOW_SIZE': 55, 
'TIMEFRAME': 53, 
'DISABLE_COMPOUNDING': 47,
'INSTANCE_MANAGEMENT': 44, 
'MAX_SPREAD': 59, 
'TIMED_EXIT_BARS': 48, 
'STRATEGY_INSTANCE_ID': 51, 
...
...
....
....
....
....
....
....
....
....
}
```

Is there something i am missing. I can't seem to get it working with items() to iterate through the Dictionary. Any help is well appreciated.

Comment: what is the value of `paramIndexes`? could be that that's key-erroring

Comment: `for k, v in OrderedDict(self.content.items('main')).items()` - calling OrderedDict on a regular dict isn't going to reach back into the past and retrieve that ordering information you never kept track of, and calling OrderedDict on an OrderedDict is kind of pointless unless you need a copy.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line:

```
self.optimizationArray[paramIndexes[k]] = (
self.mainParams[k]['start'], self.mainParams[k]['step'], self.mainParams[k]['stop'])
```

Since you had just created `self.mainParams[k]['start']`, `self.mainParams[k]['step']` and `self.mainParams[k]['stop']`, those aren't raising the error. The only culprit left is `paramIndexes[k]` and/or `self.optimizationArray[paramIndexes[k]]`

I would double **check that** `paramIndexes` **has** `k` **and that** `self.optimizationArray` **has** whatever `paramIndexes[k]` maps to.

This problem has nothing to do with OrderedDict. It's just a KeyError.